Payload empty when send as new FormData()
I'm trying to pass images to my node server but whatever i'm trying the payload is constantly empty when I pass it as a const formData = new FormData();, as regular I do get the correct informations (except for the images that cannot be translated without the new FormData()) but the rest is sent through the payload.
This is my API:
/// POST SEND MESSAGE  ///

export const postSendMessage = async (id, data) => {
  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'Accept-Language': currentLang,
  }
  const body = {
    senderId: data.senderId,
    text: data.text,
    images: data.images,
  }
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(`http://localhost:3001/patient/${id}/message`, body, { headers })
    return response
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.error('error', error);
  }
  return null
};

And this is the Frontend:
const ChatMessageInput = ({ conversationId }) => {

  const userContext = useContext(AuthContext);
  const fileRef = useRef(null);

  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

  const handleAttach = (event) => {
    const newImage = event.target.files[0];
    if (newImage && newImage.type.includes('image')) {
      setImages(prevImages => [...prevImages, newImage]);
    }
  };

  const handleChangeMessage = useCallback((event) => {
    setMessage(event.target.value);
  }, []);

  const handleSendMessage = async (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      try {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('text', message);
        formData.append('images', images);
        formData.append('senderId', userContext.user.id);
        const messageSent = await API.postSendMessage(conversationId, formData);

        setMessage('');
        setImages([]);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <InputBase
        value={message}
        onKeyUp={handleSendMessage}
        onChange={handleChangeMessage}
        placeholder="Type a message"
        endAdornment={
          <Stack direction="row">
            <IconButton onClick={() => fileRef.current.click()}>
              <Iconify icon="solar:gallery-add-bold" />
            </IconButton>

          </Stack>
        }
      />
      <input type="file" ref={fileRef} style={{ display: 'none' }} onChange={handleAttach} />
    </>
  );
}

From what I understand you cannot console.log formData, but when I console.log messages or images I do get the correct value.
I'm missing something here.
Thank you

First, When you need to append multiple images to the formData, you shouldn't pass the images array, but append them individually, for example "image" + index as a key and the image as a value.
Second, in the postSendMessage method, the second parameter is formData, you need to pass it as it is to the axios post request.
export const postSendMessage = async (id, formData) => {
  const headers = {
    'Accept-Language': currentLang, // Do not set Content-Type here
  }
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(`http://localhost:3001/patient/${id}/message`, formData, {
      headers: headers,
    });
    return response;
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.error('error', error);
  }
  return null;
};

const handleSendMessage = async (event) => {
  if (event.key === 'Enter') {
    try {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('text', message);
      formData.append('senderId', userContext.user.id);
      images.forEach((image, index) => {
        formData.append(`images[${index}]`, image);
      });
      const messageSent = await API.postSendMessage(conversationId, formData);

      setMessage('');
      setImages([]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
};


Yep it did work, got a new error but at least the payload is sent, thank you!
